# Autocompletion in Python shell only when it makes sense

Tags: python, shell, autocomplete, readline

I can enable autocompletion uning tab for python on a linux terminal using the following code:

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

However you cannot use normal tabs as indents anymore (for example inside loops of if-statements) and when you copy-paste code containing tabs in the python shell the code won't work.

Is there any way to autocomplete only when it makes sense as in pycharm, for example? Alternatively, what is the syntax to parse and bind Shift+Tab (S-tab does not work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found ptpython [ptpython](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/ptpython/), which can be easily embedded in a shell. 
Edit: that project has too many features for me. I can use ipython instead of the python shell